# DataTables warning with dedupe on find & merge (after upgrade to 4.7.18)

Tags: javascript, duplicate-contacts, datatables

Is anyone else seeing a new DataTables warning in 4.7.18? We get the following warning on the dedupe page when finding duplicate contacts:

**[Server Name] says:**

> DataTables warning: table id=dupePairs - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. 
>     For more information about this error, 
>     please see http://datatables.net/tn/3**

(Joomla version 3.6.5, php 5.6.30, mysql 5.6.36)
Thanks.

Comment: I am also getting this on 4.7.18 under Drupal 7.54.

Comment: Me too - have you found a solution? 

Comment: No, we're still getting the warning.

Comment: Just looking at this problem. Does anyone know why there would be three separate installs of DataTables on my CiviCRM? I have:

- civicrm/bower_components/datatables
- civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/DataTables
- civicrm/packages/jquery/plugins/DataTables-1.7.6

Comment: I am seeing this error on 4.7.18 under WordPress 4.7.5. Not urgent for now, but would like to be able to dedup contacts...

Comment: Having the same issue, this been resolved yet?

Answer (score 1):

There's a fix for this issue in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10503. Hope this will be included in 4.7.21.